# How to wait for a window to finish its painting in Win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, window

I use the function PrintWindow to get the screenshot of a certain window.

However, due to certain reason, the call to PrintWindow usually triggered when the window is drawing itself, and thus some parts of the window which have not been drawn yet are totally black.

Any solution to wait for the window to finish its painting?

[image: bad screenshot gotten]

Comment: This does not make much sense, the application should perform the drawing into the `WM_PAINT`, which is not interrupted by `PrintWindow` (that actually sends a `WM_PRINT` and then probably `WM_PRINTCLIENT`). There's more going on here.

Comment: Is this in the same thread/process? Do you have control of the window that is repainting itself?

Comment: as you can see in the screenshot, it's Visual Studio window, my application is a different thread

Comment: @Paul: I'd say a different *process*. Still, the Windows API should be automagically correctly synchronized, it should not be a problem.

Comment: oh yes, i meant 'different process', not 'different thread' in the previous comment

Comment: You are using VS2010, it uses WPF.  Not your plain jane GDI rendering anymore, it is hardware accelerated through DirectX.

Comment: @hans: but sometimes it can take the screenshot properly, meaning PrintWindow is still working with WPF. quite strange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Waiting for the window to finish its painting is not the solution to the problem. Or, put another way, the problem is not that `PrintWindow` is called whilst the target window is part way through its paint cycle.

`PrintWindow` functions by posting a `WM_PRINT` (or `WM_PRINTCLIENT`) message to the target window and then waiting for the target window's message queue to process that message. Queued messages do not interleave.

In order to get to the bottom of the actual problem I think you will need to supply more details.

Comment: Also remember that not all windows/controls support the `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message.

Comment: it is black like that, but sometimes the screenshot is taken properly. this seems to mean that the window and all the controls inside support WM_PRINTCLIENT. the problem is likely that i call PrintWindow when window of VS2010 is painting halfway?

Comment: @Paul "The problem is likely that I call PrintWindow when window of VS2010 is painting halfway". You said that already. I'm sure that's not the case as I said.

Comment: @David: as Hans Passant says in the comment below the question, might be the problem of WPF? because when i test, old win32 apps never get this unwanted black screen, it only goes wrong with new applications like VS2010, Windows 7 Explorer, etc.