# How to get screenshot of WPF application in VC++?

Tags: c++, wpf, windows, winapi, visual-c++

How to get screenshot of WPF application in VC++?

In VC++, I have HWND to a window which is WPF application. Traditional method using GDI PrintWindow doesn't work properly on WPF application (get a black screen when the WPF is slow in rendering). Any other method to take screenshot of a WPF application as HBITMAP?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was the problem with the GDI PrintWindow?

Comment: i'm facing this blackout problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360833/how-to-wait-for-a-window-to-finish-its-painting-in-win32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would [GetDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) & [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) change anything for the GDI+ scenario??